# Problem with inverting DC/DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am using an inverting DC/DC converter from TI (TPS6735)(5V,200ma). When connecting a load of 100ohms it's output dramatically drops to -1V.May I know why it happening like that.Sending my schematic along with this mail.output is taken across C22.[image]

Comment: What is the saturation current of the inductor?

Comment: What voltage does your 5V input supply maintain under load on the -5V output?

Comment: If it works fine with no load or a light load (1 mA, 5 kohms) but not with 50 mA (100 ohms) then I would also suspect that the inductor is saturating. Which inductor did you use ??

Comment: HI Ignacio inductor saturation current is 110ma.Do we need to use inductor with more saturation current.

Comment: Hi Andy when load is connected voltage at -5V terminal will become  -1V.

Comment: Hi Rimpelbekkie the inductor which we are using is MLZ2012N100LT000.

Comment: Use "@" (e.g. @foo) if you want to direct a comment at someone.

Comment: By far that MLZ2012... cannot store enough energy to make your circuit work at 200 mA, you need something looking more like this https://www.westfloridacomponents.com/G450APF06/10uH+SMT+Inductor+JW+Miller+PM43-100M.html  This is just an example, there are many different models that are suitable. But note the thick wire and the magnetic core !

Answer (score 2):

Your inductor is *far* too small for your application. If you want to draw 50mA then you need an inductor that can handle at least 600mA, and for a full 200mA it will need to be able to handle about 1.3A.

From the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tps6735):

[image]

Comment: This is 100% correct and to be clear, we are not talking about inductor value being too small but inductor SIZE ! You need an inductor that can store a lot of (magnetic) energy and these are physically large.